# Map Point arrow

Tags: geometry

Im doing some software with Silverlight.

Im drawing some Polylines in a Map given some points.

In the first photo there are shown three ponts.
They are connected with some esri polyline function.

But now i need to draw an arrow figure at the end of the line connectid to the various points.
So for me to be able that arrow figure I need to figure the x and y point on which that arrow will be.
(For this I meant what can be seet on the second image x=? and y=?)

The system is coordenate system of the planet.

I will be very glad if u could help me.
The x and y data are not exactly accurate, but I hope u can tell me the way of calculating those points to simulate the arrow.

[mappointimagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZR1Sh.png)